# Syntax error when trying to create a database with name: 9e1617bafr1_1

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

yesterday I stumbled upon a weird problem.

I have a PHP script that creates mysql databases for me based of some input.

When the script tried to generate a database with the name "9e1617bafr1_1" (without quotes) and I got this error "MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax".

Query is `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 9e1617bafr1_1`

I also get the error when trying to execute it on https://de.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ and http://sqlfiddle.com/

I resolved it by using backticks before and after the database name but I'm still wondering why I got this error in the first place as the creation of "9d1617bafr1_1", "9f1617bafr1_1" and so on worked flawlessly.

Unfortunately I did not find anything useful on this behavior on the internet and as I'm very curious about it I wanted to ask if anybody know if this is a reserved word or if it violates the SQL standard in any way?

Comment: this because your name begin with digit and not with char .   try e91617bafr1_1

Comment: No, it's not a MySQL reserved word. And, no, it doesn't violate the SQL standard... I believe the standard leaves rules for identifiers up to the implementation. (Different databases have different rules, and I believe the rules are "compliant" with the standard.) The MySQL error is because the parser sees the token "9e1617" as a *numeric literal*, where an *identifier* is expected.

Answer (score 2):

9e1617bafr1_1 is parsed as number (9e1617) followed by a character string (bafr1_1). Your other attempts, "9d1617bafr1_1", and "9f1617bafr1_1", don't start with scientific notation, so they don't get parsed that way.